# get length of second dimension of array

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I found different post on this topic but I could not find a suitable solution nor understand the code. Anyway, I do have an array that works like a non-squared matrix with columns and rows. From that array I want to retrieve the number of columns and rows later on.

```
this.myArray = new AreaTuple[cols][rows];
```

But how? I know how this works in C# but not in Java.

Comment: So you want the length of `myArray`? Or the length of a column?

Comment: The length of each dimension: columns and rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number of Rows

```
this.myArray.length;
```

Number of Columns

```
this.myArray[0].length;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can check length of your array, like:

```
this.myArray.length; // for row count
```

and...

```
this.myArray[0].length; //for column count
```

Note: Remember that 2-D array is actually an array containing other arrays (an array of array).

Answer (score 2):

Basically this will return length of second dimension:

```
this.myArray[0].length;
```

Remember that two-dimensional array is just an array of arrays, which means that if you take one object of this main array, you will be able to check it's length.

Answer (score 0):

For cols:

```
System.out.println(AreaTuple[0].length);
```

For rows:

```
System.out.println(AreaTuple.length);
```

Comment: rows example is wrong